# Send recorded video using getUserMedia through form without using FormData

Tags: javascript, php, blob, getusermedia

I have a form where users can record themselves with their webcam using getUserMedia, and I need to send the file they record to another page before saving the file to the server.

My question is how can I achieve this? So far I've generated a blob of the video, how do I send this through my form to the next page so I can access the file and then store it on the server?

Currently I'm generating the blob like so, which works:

`let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob, {autoRevoke: false});`

But I'm not sure how I can send this file as part of the form's POST request without using AJAX and FormData. Is it even possible or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: "*what would be the best way to do that*" What constitutes the best *anything* is highly subjective, questions of which type are explicitly off-topic per the scope of Stack Overflow defined in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm just asking how this can be achieved. Sorry if the word choice maybe wasn't the best.

Comment: _Why_ without using AJAX & FormData? You _could_ serialize your video blob into a format you can stick into a hidden form field (base64 for example), and then submit the form "the normal way" - but that wouldn't necessarily win you anything (on the contrary, base64 encoding is going to increase the data volume by 4/3.)

Comment: Yeah, I don't know much about it but it seemed to me base64 encoding a video file might not work the best, especially if the video file is too large. Right now sending the file via AJAX/FormData works fine if I send it directly to the processing script and save it right away, but I'm trying to send it to another page first where the user will enter more info, and THEN send everything to the server to be saved. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file from your blob add it to a FileList and then overwrite the FileList of a file input in the form.

```
<form>
    ...
    <input type="file" name="myvideo" id="fileinput">
    ...
</form>
```

```
var input = document.querySelector('#fileinput'); //the file input
var file = new File(blob, 'video_file.mp4'); // create new file
// Need to use a data transfer object to get a new FileList object
var datTran = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer(); 
datTran.items.add(file);  // Add the file to the DT object
input.files = datTran.files; // overwrite the input file list with ours
```

Comment: I think this is the route I'm gonna take, I tried it from an answer I found on another question on SO and it does work (at least in updated browsers). I'm not really sure how to handle a user that's using a browser that doesn't support it, though. I guess I could just display a message to the user and disable the form.