upload audio blob to server and save as file
I have 3 buttons to rec, stop and play audio.
Using MediaRecorder is easy to get an audio blob running.
Problems arise when I try to upload the blob as a file to the server.
I have an audio element whose type is file, a recording flag (0 or 1), and need to upload the blob when I stop the recording.
This is my code:

var thisAudioBlob = document.getElementById("audioElement");
var playFlag = 0;

function initFunction() {
  async function getUserMedia(constraints) {
    if (window.navigator.mediaDevices) {
      return window.navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
    }
    let legacyApi =
      navigator.getUserMedia ||
      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
      navigator.msGetUserMedia;
    if (legacyApi) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        legacyApi.bind(window.navigator)(constraints, resolve, reject);
        return reject('rejected');
      });
      } else {
      // === an alert
      }
  }
  
  let audioChunks = [];
  let rec;
  let blob; 

  function handlerFunction(stream) {
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
      rec.start();
      rec.ondataavailable = (e) => {
          audioChunks.push(e.data);
          if (rec.state == "inactive") {
            blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/mp3" });
            blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            document.getElementById("audioElement").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var recordedAudioPath = document.getElementById("audioElement").src;
            tempAudioFilePathField.value = recordedAudioPath;
            recordedAudioFlag = 1;
          }
      };
    }
  
  function startusingBrowserMicrophone(boolean) {
      getUserMedia({ audio: boolean }).then((stream) => {
          handlerFunction(stream);
      });
    }

    startusingBrowserMicrophone(true);
  
    myStopButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (playFlag != 1) {
        try {
              new File([thisAudioBlob], "audio_temp.mp3", {
                type: thisAudioBlob.type,
                lastModified:new Date().getTime()
              });
        } catch(error) {
          // === manage error
        }

        rec.stop();
        audioNoteFlagField.value = "1";
      } else {
        playFlag = 0;
        thisAudioBlob.pause();
        bulletIconDiv.style.color = "white";
        myPlayButton.style.color = "white";
        document.getElementById("audioElement").currentTime = 0.01;
        audioText.textContent = "play per ascoltare...";
        try {
          new File([thisAudioBlob], "audio_temp.mp3", {
              type: thisAudioBlob.type,
              lastModified:new Date().getTime()
           });
           audioSaveAjax();
        } catch(error) {
           // === manage error
        }
      }
    });
}

function audioSaveAjax() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('fname', 'test_audio_file.mp3');
  fd.append('data', thisAudioBlob);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ‘get_audio.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
   }).done(function(data) {
    // === say something through console
  });
}

But  don't get an audio file. I only get a 25 nonsense bytes file and nothing else.
What am I doing wrong?
Any help?

You are appending the HTMLAudioElement to the FormData object, you should be appending the blob you create from the audio chunks.
To get the blob in the ajax function you could use the jQuery data method, see below.
...
blob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: "audio/mp3" });
$(thisAudioBlob).data('blob', blob);
...

function audioSaveAjax() {
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('fname', 'test_audio_file.mp3');
  fd.append('data', $(thisAudioBlob).data('blob'), 'free the.mp3');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'get_audio.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
   }).done(function(data) {
    // === say something through console
  });
}


It's returning "undefined"  : (

Make sure the blob was created. Check if blob == undefined

Sure it was created, since I play the recorded audio. Better to say, I play the audioElement that points to the URL.createObjectURL(blob). Maybe the blob problem is a matter of scope as for variables? I create the blob inside handlerFunction, while now I try to post it using a function outside, that's called from a listener still outside handlerFunction. Is there a way to make the blob a sort of global?

Okay, I guess I missed the scope, see update

Seems not so easy. It returns: "TypeError: Argument 2 ('blobValue') to FormData.append must be an instance of Blob".

could also choose a workaround: put audioElement inside a separate form, and submit that form via Ajax. But things might require a little more tuning, because since the usual "data: form.serialize()" cannot apply to input type='file', what's the right syntax to Ajax submit form with a file?

Strange that the data function didn't work, I guess you can always use a global variable. window.blob = new Blob. If you want to add a file to a input see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71200356/send-recorded-video-using-getusermedia-through-form-without-using-formdata.

I'll give a try to your solution found in the thread you hilted here. Will come back with result later on.

Nope. We're always at starting point: no blob variable is found outside the function where it is created. The problem is all there: how to get and use a blob outside the damn function (or listener) where it has been created. So, maybe we have to take the content of "thisAudioBlob" object (thisAudioBlob = document.getElementById("audioElement");), see my code, which is an HTML audio object (<audio src='' id='audioElement' style='display: none;'></audio>), and use that content to build the file. But how to take it for our purposes?  Any suggestion?

Have a look to my demo here: https://vrobbi-webrtc-demo.glitch.me/uploadvideo
It works fine, registering video, play video, upload video and delete video.
No library used, pure javascript.
It should be a good example to help you how to resolve.
Look at the variable  'recordedBlobs'
